# How to resolve Javascript fetch API error in browser when sending POST request to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, post, fetch-api

I have a RESTful API in Spring Boot with a few endpoints implemented. Tomcat is running fine on port 8080, and Postman requests get a response, but I get errors when trying to fetch from the browser.

The script:

```
  let candy = {
    id: id, //previously declared id variable being passed
    flavor: 0
  };
  fetch('localhost:8080/api/candy', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(candy)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.message);
  });
```

POST request in Postman to:

```
localhost:8080/api/candy
```

with body:

```
{
    "id": 243,
    "flavor": 2
}
```

returns:

```
{
    "id": 243,
    "flavor": 2
}
```

which is what I expect.

The welcome page from Tomcat opens just fine when I visit `localhost:8080`, but I don't know why it can't send the POST request. The errors both in Chrome and Opera are:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 //this one only under Chrome
Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/api/candy. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Any ideas?

Edit: under Opera I get the
 `Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/api/candy. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.` error, but it is probably the same thing.

Comment: The error message is self-explaining: you need to use the full URL `http://localhost:8080/api/candy`, not part of it `localhost:8080/api/candy`. Although browsers nowadays tend to hide the scheme part of the URL, it is still required.

Comment: Yes @PiotrP.Karwasz, thank you, I added the http protocol and it solved the problem, indeed, but I don't understand why it's not required in Postman.  Does Postman automatically append it?

Comment: Yes, it must apply some heuristic to the string you enter and so do the browsers.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind making this an answer so that I could accept it? @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `fetch()` should be the URL of the requested resource. You use just `localhost:8080/api/candy`, which lacks the scheme.

Use:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/candy
```

instead.

Most tools (browsers, postman) nowadays, don't show the scheme of the current page, but it is nevertheless required.